# Exclude Overheads while Haskell Profiling

Tags: haskell, annotations, profiling, ghc

Is there a good way to exclude certain functional calls from profiling in Haskell?

I'm loading in a large binary dump of a dictionary, which takes a couple of second and completely eclipses the bits of the code I'm interested in.

```
COST CENTRE          MODULE     %time %alloc

read_wordlist        Wordlists   93.6   98.3
solve                Solver       1.3    0.0
anagrams             Evaluation   0.8    1.4
[...]
```

For reference, I'm loading the dictionary like this

```
read_wordlist = do
    ls <- fmap Text.lines (Text.readFile "data/straight-wordlist")
    (return . Data.Set.fromList . string_read . toString . Prelude.head) ls
```

and all the code is separated in modules (but pretty vanilla, etc.).

Is there some arrangement of SCC annotations that means I can do all my overhead loading sneakily and not have it count towards my overall stats?

Comment: Have you tried moving `Data.Set.fromList . string_read . toString . Prelude.head . Text.lines` into a separate function so that all `read_wordlist` does is read from the file then call this function?  I'd suggest some strictness annotations with `BangPatterns` as well so that you can pinpoint exactly where your time is being spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with GHC 7.8, you can do:

```
import GHC.Profiling
import Control.Deepseq

main = do
    stopProfTimer
    wordlist <- read_wordlist
    return $!! wordlist -- Ensure it is fully evaluated in the untimed section
    startProfTimer
    print (solve wordlist)
```

This only seems to stop collection of time statistics though, not allocation.

Comment: Ah, I was crawling through the manual looking for 'Reset timer' 'exclude from profiling' etc - this is great.

Comment: Does this package still exist? I can't seem to find it in cabal or on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/), although there is a ghost of a reference someway back in time (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/GHC-Profiling.html)

Comment: I meant the one you linked to. But how is it "back in time"? `base-4.7.0.0` is the version that comes with GHC 7.8. Apparently it's new in this version though (I'll amend the answer).